# Symfony: How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically add a new input field using the official cookbook tutorial:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

but using **POST_SUBMIT** event (as the official tutorial suggests) I get the following error:

> You cannot add children to a submitted form

Comment: Where exactly in the symfony's documentation is wrote that you are allowed to change a form field using the `POST_SUBMIT` event?

Comment: @gp_sflover as I wrote in my question: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: In the linked example the `POST_SUBMIT` event was never used to add a new field to the form. I think you need to update the post with adding all the code related to your problem.

Comment: @gp_sflover Did you read the whole paragraph that I liked? "Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms", second code block, line 41

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Form Events docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html). The last event you can use for modifying the form is `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event.

Comment: that is what I thought, but then it means that the cookbook tutorial is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Tutorial is correct. There are no any mention in tutorial you've posted that it is allowed to add/remove children on POST_SUBMIT event.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms   paragraph "Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms", second code block, line 41

Comment: I see, but there are no any addition of the child fields in listener callback there

Comment: @ShinDarth for that is better if you update your post with the code otherwise it's impossible to find the error. PS: I accidentally removed my previous comment.

Comment: that event listener calls $formModifier which calls $form->add    (line 23)

Comment: Your are right, but they pass not current form to this callback, but its parent. I think at that moment current form is considered as submitted but its parent still not.